# Retrieve most recently created file

Tags: javascript, android

Newbie question. So I have two activities. One the User creates a recording, and the other he is able to play that recording.

How do I connect *buttonPlayLastRecordAudio* to the audio just recently created in the previous activity?

my audio save path in Activity #1 is:

```
AudioSavePathInDevice =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "AudioRecording.3gp";
```

Activity #2:

```
final String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(true);

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(baseDir);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(SendActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: just save the path in shared preferences and access in another activity

Comment: @jagapathi Awesome, thanks allot man.